# Integration of Outlook calendar, GSUIT calendar And iCal programatically C#

Tags: outlook

I have a specific requirement, I have a .Net Application where I have some dates, so I want to create appointments for these dates in Outlook, GSuit and iCal calendar.

Can someone help me to give steps to create these appointments programmatically C#.

I tried to achieve by adding reference Microsoft.Office.interop.outlook and below code. i got this code from Microsoft site but I have difficulty to replace "this". what code should replace "this" in below code.

````
       {
           try
           {               
               Outlook.AppointmentItem newAppointment =
                   (Outlook.AppointmentItem)
                   this.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
               newAppointment.Start = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
               newAppointment.End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);
               newAppointment.Location = "ConferenceRoom #2345";
               newAppointment.Body =
                   "We will discuss progress on the group project.";
               newAppointment.AllDayEvent = false;
               newAppointment.Subject = "Group Project";
               newAppointment.Recipients.Add("Roger Harui");
               Outlook.Recipients sentTo = newAppointment.Recipients;
               Outlook.Recipient sentInvite = null;
               sentInvite = sentTo.Add("Holly Holt");
               sentInvite.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType
                   .olRequired;
               sentInvite = sentTo.Add("David Junca ");
               sentInvite.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType
                   .olOptional;
               sentTo.ResolveAll();
               newAppointment.Save();
               newAppointment.Display(true);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("The following error occurred: " + ex.Message);
           }```
````

Comment: [This link](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook/Application/CreateItem/php-application-createitem-method-examples.html) shows you how you can use `this.Application`.

Comment: I am getting An unhandled exception of type Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).. Please provide the solution.i am getting this error at line Outlook._Application outlookObj = new Outlook.Application();